# Cannot start uwsgi on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, trying to do a Nginx + uWsgi + Django setup. I've followed this tutorial to the letter: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04.

The uWsgi ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
project = san_project
uid = ubuntu

base = /home/%(uid)
chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown‐socket = %(uid):www‐data
chmod‐socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

The Nginx server block file,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 115.159.216.67;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/san_project;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/san_project.sock;
    }
}
```

and the systemd service file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash ‐c 'sudo mkdir ‐p /run/uwsgi; sudo chown ubuntu:www‐data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi ‐‐emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi‐user.target
```

Everything goes fine until I try to start uWsgi, and I'm guessing that the problem is in the .service file.

When I do `sudo systemctl start uwsgi`, the error is: **Job for uwsgi.service failed because the control process exited with error code**. So I do a `systemctl status uwsgi.service`, and I see that the problem happens at the `ExecStartPre` line, I ran that line in command line and seems like they didn't have permission to create the directory or change its owners so I added `sudo` into front of these.

Now when I try to start the uwsgi server, I get the same error as before in the command line, but the really strange thing is that I can't even see any details on the error is because when I try to do `systemctl status uwsgi.service` it either says: **Failed to get properties: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without reply**, OR it says: **Failed to get properties: Connection timed out**.

Restarting the server doesn't work, shutting it down and restarting it doesn't work.

I'm running this on a Chinese company's cloud, Tencent Cloud. Not sure if that makes a difference, since I don't really know what's special about them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, pulling my hair out here for hours and hours.

Comment: Are you able run following? uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/ubuntu/Env/san_project --chdir /home/ubuntu/san_project -w san_project.wsgi

Comment: @zatta yes, when I run it the website works - i.e., I can go visit 115.159.216.67:8080 and I see the Welcome to Django page.

Comment: There's another strange thing, is that after I run `sudo systemctl start uwsgi` enough times the entire server just slows the WAY down. I've done several re-installs and this always happens. By slow I mean login is slow, I type in a command and it takes several seconds for the server to respond, etc... makes me think something in the background is eating up a lot of resources??

Comment: Could you replace processes=5 with workers=2 and try again? Though, as there is no worker_class set in your config, it should again still create 2 processes but that should use lot less ram I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be caused by an extremely n00b mistake.

While following the guide, I copied the setting files from the website (or the PDF I printed out from the site, don't remember). I even copied the code into Notepad (yes I'm on Windows) to make sure nothing weird got copied over, but apparently all the hyphens were replaced by some strange character that looks EXACTLY like a hyphen inside Sublime Text.

So of course when I upload all these files, especially the `uwsgi.service` file, it gives me a 127 error code (file not found), but when I execute all the commands in command line they all work fine ...

I only discovered the problem when I used VI to look at my files and saw it was filled with these strange symbols where the hyphen should be.

Hard lesson learned... but it's very interesting how the website / PDF copy would turn a hyphen into some strange character.